# Bitmap becoming null

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

First I create a new bitmap

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Game.panel.context.getResources(),R.drawable.dinofront)
```

Then I stretch the image, after this I check if the bitmap is null, it is not

```
image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, Game.tileWidth, Game.tileHeight, false);
```

Later in the draw() method, before I do anything with the bitmap, I check again and it is now null. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Is there anything special I have to do that I am missing?

Full classes: http://pastebin.com/t95MVvv0

Comment: If you don't post your entire code, we can't help you, because the code you posted looks normal. I suggest you to find in your project if you modify the image variable somewhere else in your code (In another thread for example).

Comment: Add the complete file

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible reasons:

1. It may simply be that the image variable may be changed by other part of your code
2. Thread synchronization - remember that codes may not be executed in the order specified in the Java source code, but can be reorder as the JVM deemed fit, which [includes assigning the instance variable before the constructor is run](http://pveentjer.wordpress.com/2007/03/18/immutability-doesnt-guarantee-thread-safety/). This is especially likely when you are doing extremely time consuming Bitmap op within the constructor, and I assume your object creation code is on a different thread than your drawing code. To check for this possibility you can declare a volatile boolean variable that is only set to true when the constructor is finished, and check its value within your `draw()` method

Answer (score 0):

Wow I feel stupid. Because there is the image for the class and the image that is brought in with the constructor when I call image = Bitmap.create... it is only setting the constructor's image not this.image so if I change it to this.image =... it all works fine